# How to capture last command within tsql stored procedure (for logging purposes)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, logging

We have a critical business process (written by a 3rd party) made up of dozens of large tsql stored procedures (some are 2000+ lines of tsql - dozens of embedded IF's & conditional logic - nightmare to debug). Multiple instances of these procedures are run concurrently.

These procedures call each other and the stack can be very deep, i.e. ProcA calls ProcB, ProcB calls ProcC & ProcC can call ProCD - you get the picture.

Delays are creeping into this process (mainly network latency querying 3rd party linked servers). We want to add tailor made event logging to the procedures to monitor key inserts, updates & so on.

SQL Profiler works fine, but is very inconvenient and a more permanent monitoring system is needed that will allow non developers to monitor the system, deal with comms issues and so on.

Currently we do this logging using simple strings at key points within the stored procedures, for example:

```
DECLARE @logstr VARCHAR(MAX) = '[' + OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID) + '] INSERT into tbl_whatever with values 1, 5 & 6'

usp_log @logstr --#### This proc records the string to a table along with datetime etc
```

As you can see, this is very verbose and is cluttering up the code. Also, having to type into the @logstr the command that was just executed takes time and is prone to errors. It would be much better if we could automatically retrieve (and log) the last statement that ran (ideally with any variable values).

I know you can use `DBCC INPUTBUFFER(@@SPID)` within a tsql procedure - but this obviously just returns the call to the procedure & not the last command WITHIN the procedure.

I've also tried using `sys.dm_exec_sql_text` within a procedure, but that just returns the `CREATE PROCEDURE` text and not the last statement within the procedure.

Is there any way to query the last statement executed within a procedure?

If not, is there a better way to log the inner-workings (and timings) of a stored procedure (with procedure name & datetime) & get the results into SQL for presentation & analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` DMV.

It references the same `SQL_Handle` value that `sys.dm_exec_sql_text` does, but crucially it can help you identify individual parts of the procedure as they are run (along with the stats) based on the `statement_start_offset` and `statement_end_offset` columns:

```
SELECT ProcName = COALESCE(OBJECT_NAME(St.objectid), 'Ad-Hoc'),
       ParentQueryText = St.Text,
       IndividualStatementText = SUBSTRING(St.text, (Qs.statement_start_offset / 2) + 1, ((CASE Qs.statement_end_offset
                                                                                             WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(St.text)
                                                                                             ELSE Qs.statement_end_offset
                                                                                           END - Qs.statement_start_offset) / 2) + 1),
       LastTimeRun = Qs.last_execution_time
FROM   sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS Qs
       CROSS APPLY sys.Dm_exec_sql_text(Qs.sql_handle) AS St
```

Comment: This looks very promising, one question though, these procedures are executed by 20 sql agent jobs - all running at the same time - obviously any logging will only want to capture IndividualStatementText from the current scope (i.e. the job that executed this particular instance) - do these views do that already? if not, how could one restrict the results?

Comment: I believe this looks at all queries running on the server, regardless of whether they are being run by users, agent jobs etc. If you need details on who or what is running the procedure, there are a bunch more DMVs you can join to - see [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46009/get-username-and-or-ip-address-responsible-for-a-query) related question on DBA.se

Comment: Your answer is built on dm_exec_query_stats, that DBA.se link you sent highlights the problem perfectly "is cumulative and aggregated statistics that aren't by session/connection" - i'm hitting a brick wall trying find a way round this problem. Will update if i find something

Comment: I understand, good point. Well, hopefully I got you part of the way there!